# How do i properly read an analog pin on attiny85?

Tags: attiny

Anyone ever run into a problem with your attiny not reading  your analog pins correctly? (-1023 or 1023 or 0 value) How did you resolve the issue?

Here's what my code looks like now :

4th revision of code as of 5/6/2015 8pm:

```
int NTC = A1; // thermistor
int switchPin = PB1; // push button
int LED = PB0;  // led 


// button latch
byte ButtonState;
byte lastState = LOW;
byte count = 0;

 //brightness level of each different mode 
int low = 50; 
int med = 140;
int high = 255;             
int dim = 0;


int ADCcount = 0;

void setup() 
{ 

 pinMode(switchPin, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);  

  }

 void loop() 
 {

  ADCcount = analogRead(NTC);  

delay(100);


  ButtonState = digitalRead(switchPin);

  if(ButtonState && ButtonState != lastState)  // button latch, no debounce      needed.
   {
      if(count < 4) // This will check to see if the count is within a range of  0 - 255 
                 // anything over that, it will reset count back to 0. Of course
      count += 1;  // same as count = count + 5;
      else 
      count == 0;
        }    

    lastState = ButtonState;

   if (count == 0)
  {analogWrite(LED,0);} 
    else if (count == 1) { if(ADCcount < 500) {analogWrite(LED,high);}
      else{ if(ADCcount > 525){analogWrite(LED,low);}
       }            
          } 
      else if (count == 2 ){analogWrite(LED,med);} 
      else if (count == 3) {analogWrite(LED,low);}
      if(count >=4) {count = 0;}
      delay(50);
 }
```

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdyIZY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Show some effort and indent your code properly. Use four spaces in front of every line of code. I'd do it myself, but I'm on a phone right now.

Comment: 350000 is a very big value for microsecond delay. The generated code might overflow and not actually wait or get stuck in an infinite loop. Use millisecond delay instead.

Comment: @FRob I switched the delay from microseconds to milliseconds but unfortunately it did not solve the issue..

Comment: Did you try to run it in debug mode with frequent stops to see the execution flow? I just do not see an infinite loop in your script. What happens after _void loop()_ is executed?

Comment: @Naz Um... it _loops_ (the function executes again). The arduino environment hides the standard main() function, declaring but not defining the setup() and loop() functions you see there, instead.

Comment: Ah.. ok. Is the error time dependent? Does everything work fine first 30 minutes? I see that the problem could be caused because when the microcontroller is working on some other program lines and you press the button, so it does not react to it. It means you must press it right before the new loop of the _loop()_ function starts. This is very difficult to do. Instead, I would recommend to introduce interrupt subroutine that will react on the pin change value (the interrupt can react on rising edge, falling edge, or both). This way, you can strictly control this input signal.

Comment: @Naz No sometimes it will lock up after five minutes, other times longer than 30 minutes. I've never heard of an interrupt sub routine, from the little ive googled it could be the way to go. know of any good examples?

Comment: I do not follow one thing - this microcontroller has no DAC. How to do perform _analogWrite_?

Comment: @Naz It sets up a hardware timer, using a output compare unit to generate a PWM waveform, with the function argument controlling the duty cycle (by affecting OCRxx). Thats why "analogWrite" is only available on certain pins.

Comment: @jms Oh, PWM sounds good.

Comment: Whats the frequency of your PWM? What kind of LED is this (datasheet)? Why isn't there a series reistor with the LED?

Comment: @Golaž I do not know what the frequency of the pwm is. 
led doesnt need a series resistor, to the extent of my knowledge.

http://www.cree.com/~/media/Files/Cree/LED%20Components%20and%20Modules/XLamp/Data%20and%20Binning/XLampCXA1512.pdf

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, no offence, but your code is utterly uggly... You're doing the same calculations in all of the switch cases, why not just make a function and call it? I am not sure what compiler you're using, but if you're declaring a variable inside a switch case one normally has to use curly braces `case x: {... break;}`. This way you'll be able to get rid of those global variables. Please clean it up a bit.

Comment: Also, you're doing quite some heavy calculations on a 8-bit uC, you're using division,log and floating point variables. On your uC there is no hardware divider neither there is a hardware floating point support. You might be missing out all those button presses due to these complex calculations. I would rethink your design... Can you linearize it?

Comment: @Golaž  no offense taken im sure the code looks fugly, im working with three months of knowledge. This is my first major coding project im using the arduino compiler. I like your function & Linearization idea ill try and clean the code up however im gonna need to do more research on how to linearize the calculations.

Comment: First try to clean the code up a bit and then edit your question. There might be a clear indication of whats wrong, but its hard to analyze it now as it is.

Comment: @Golaž I put all the same calculations in the switch cases because of the if statement.( at the very end of the case said if steinhart > 30 analog write led etc. etc.) when i made the function for temperature and a function for the switch case i could no longer write an if statement to read the temperature then write the led output. How would you go around this?

Comment: Your code is better now. However, I dont have enough time today to take a closer look, will check it tommorow.

Comment: 1) How is the thermistor wired? The pin assignments in your code do not fit your schematic. 2) The switch pin should be configured as `INPUT`. 3) What should happen when count = 1 and 500 ≤ ADCcount ≤ 525? 4) Why use two delays in loop() instead of a single 150 ms delay? 5) The test for `count >= 4` at the end of loop() is useless. 6) A switch/case on `count` would make the code more readable. 7) Constants should be declared `const`.

Answer (score 1):

The improper bush-button event handling is likely to cause the problem. One way to properly react to the external environment signals could be constant polling or using interrupts. With constant polling, all the time is spent on the checking the status of the button. With interrupts, the program is executed as it should, and only if interrupt happens - the execution jumps to the interrupt subroutine, executes it, and goes back to the main code where it left off.

In your case, you can use pin 7, for example, for push button signal. It can have a function of *INT0*. Read *Section 9. Interrupts* of the datasheet - it is straight forward.

I do not completely understand what your program should do, but I will try to convey the general approach of using subroutines:

```
volatile bool pressed = false;
int main(void)
   {
   MCUCR |= (1<<ISC01 |1<<ISC00);       // set INT0 to interrupt on rising edge of pin7
   sei();                               // enable global interrupts

   while(1){
      if (pressed) then do something; //You can disable interrupts here so your code is not interrupted by cli();
      pressed = false; // reset the state
      else do something else;
   // you can re-enable your interrupts here by sei();
   }        
}

// only happens when the change on pin 7 is from LOW to HI 
ISR(INT0_vect){
pressed = true; // update the pressed status
}
```

If you want to use pin6 for push button, you should enable the PCINT1 instead of INT0 and change the ISR to handle the PCINT1 interrupt. In this case, pin 6 will react on voltage toggle (from HI to LOW, or the other way) and you can not discriminate rizing/falling edges. In that way, you must read pin6 within the instruction subroutine to know if it is hi or low.

**EDIT:**

I would suggest to stop the calculations in the *Temp()* function after the

```
  average = SERIESRESISTOR / average;
```

line due to the fact that you have only three operating modes for the LED. Thus you can, back calculate the *average* value that makes your *steinhart* value to be, for example >30. This way, all other values greather/smaller than that value will also fall under the same condition depending on whether average/steinhart are directly/inversely proportional.

When you determine the three ranges of raw *average* values you can use them directly in the *Mode()* function. Eventually, you can optimize you code even further, by performing monotonic read instead of burst reads. If you keep a buffer, you do only one addition of the most recent sample and subtracting the oldest sample. For this you will need two pointers and one memory for to store *sum*, but you will not need to do nSamples additions:

```
read (newSample);
sum += newSample;
sum -= oldestSample;
average = sum/numSamples;
update pointers to the memory for oldest sample and for the feature sample;
```

Comment: 350ms should be ample time for the button to settle. Currently, he constantly polls, but when pressing the button for a short amount of time, it should work as is. Of course, pressing and holding it will cycle through all "modes" (counter) without ever giving a reading.

Comment: @Naz would I place this code under the void loop ?also should i include the int main?

Comment: @FRob is there a way for when the button is held down it doesnt cycle through all the modes?

Comment: I use Atmel Studio and this is how standard mix of C and assembly is written. I do know what should be written in Arduino environment.

Comment: @Naz I downloaded atmel studio yesterday learning how to program with atmel is next on my list.

Comment: @Naz You have a couple of mistakes in your code. `pressed` should be outside of main and defined as `volatile`. Secondly, delay shouldn't be in an `ISR` put that into main.

Comment: @Golaž You are right: _Pressed_ is moved, the _delay_ is removed. I tried to convey the concept idea instead of proper programming code. But for the sake of correctness, please, feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: @Naz I tried to implement your interrupt for the push button but i must have done it wrong because now the push button doesnt work at all.

Comment: @Naz Ill use my second arduino to run the thermistor sketch and monitor the raw resistor values to cut down on the temp code but how to do i create a pointer for memory and update that pointer?